Are the 3 Acharas and 5 makaras a part of Kashmir Shaivism?
I have been learning about Kashmir Shaivism and it personally looks more philosophical than ritualistic.
I have been trying to find the 5 makaras and the 3 Acharas which are a prominent part of Tantra in Trika texts but I am unable to find them.
They seem to be practised more in Shakta Tantra which is more ritualistic in nature but it doesn't seem the same in Trika Shaivism.
Can someone provide me the information about which Kashmir Shaiva texts talk about rituals relating the 5 makaras and the 3 Acharas?
And what Trika texts in general talk about rituals present in Kashmir Shaivism?
